# invalid link to data source cell in creating template instance in tosca

Tags: automation, automated-tests, tosca

[image]

received below error while instantiation in tosca

I have created test sheet and linked to template. Trying to convert it into template instance but abpve error is received

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to some syntax issue. Some extra spaces or tabs in the script when you added xl{reference}
Do check template before you Intantiate the Template.
Right click on Test case template and click on Check Template.
It will give you if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today. It seems to occur when you change Excel and try to reinstantiate.

The following fix worked for me:

- I deleted the already instantiated test cases, including the folder TemplateInstance of ...
- Then I instantiated the test case anew. It prompted me to relink the data source. In this situation, it correctly reads the newly added lines in the Excel.
- No further issues encountered.

The only drawback is that all previously added execution lists will be affected. You'll need to add your test cases again.